# How to properly describe a half-finished student project on my resume

Tags: resume

I was doing a double degree program where I worked on a project counting for both degrees. Only the first half of the project counted for my first degree while the whole project counted for my second degree.

I quit my second degree program after finishing the part of the project needed for my first degree, so now I have a half-finished project on my hands. But the thing is, the title of the project does not reflect at all what I have done. The first part was mainly theoretical stuff and proofs while the second was supposed to be the application with more concrete results.

I understand that I need to name the project to reflect the work that was done, not what it was supposed to be. But can I include the fact that it was part of a bigger one, even though I did not do that part (and will never finish it)?
I would prefer to add that the project was also applicable, rather than all theoretical but since I did not do any of the application part, I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: Half finished projects will hardly impress anyone. Focus on the (realized) outcomes and achievements of your work. If the work has a strong practical application you can also say that, without mentioning unfinished work.

Comment: Leave it off your resume.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in resumes you only state what work experience you had. If you worked on a project for 5 month and that only entailed theoretical work, just state that from x to y you worked on theoretical project a (for development of application b).
If it is part of you education degree, and you got the degree, one can assume the the project was in itself successful to the goals and requirements of that degree.

You can talk about the outcome, possible applications and why they where never made, when the topic is brought up in an actual interview.